# Metric of $n$-torus

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The metric of a $2$-torus can be written as
\begin{align}
ds^2&=\frac{e^\psi}{\tau_2}|dy_1-\tau\,dy_2|^2\\
&=\frac{e^\psi}{\tau_2}(dy_1^2-2\tau_1dy_1dy_2+|\tau|^2dy_2^2)
\end{align}
where $e^\psi$ parametrizes the the area of the torus and $\tau=\tau_1+i\tau_2$ is the complex structure of the torus. Can this be generalized to the metric of an $n$-torus (with $n\in\mathbb{N}$)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $g$ is a metric on the $n$-torus $T$, is there a conformal diffeomorphism $(T, g) \to \mathbb R^n / \Lambda$ for some lattice $\Lambda$?

Comment: $n$ will have to be even, right?

Comment: @JohnMa, yes I would say there is (but to be fair, I am a physicist who needs this metric, not a mathematician). If this is true (about the conformal diffeomorphism), how does that help exactly? Thanks in advance.